# windows phone8.1 support winjs/javascript as native already?

Tags: windows-phone-8, winjs

I'm wondering if the Windows Phone 8.1 SDK supports WinJS? I saw there are some news that windows phone 8.1 start to support WinJS

If so, I will move to WinJS for WP and WinRT both.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the combination of Windows Phone 8.1 and WinJs 2.1 will allow you to build cross platform WinJs based applications.

[Source](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/buildingapps/archive/2014/04/02/bringing-winjs-cross-platform-and-open-source.aspx)

Universal apps written in Xaml also will be a very good way to share code across the two platforms with minimal changes.